# How do we simplify the formula of finding unit vector in the direction of a given vector?

Tags: vectors

Q: Find a unit vector in direction of $\vec{a}$ = 2i+2j.

My solution:

1. Now , We know unit vectors are I,j,k.
   So , for a vector to be a unit vector in direction of some other vector. Both vectors need to be collinear.

Answer is : I+j . This is by guessing.

[image]

1.5) Another way I think about it is that if we were to find a unit vector in the direction of a vector 2i. The vector can be 0.1i , 0.7i , 0.007i. Any of it but since a unit has value 1. We only write 1i as answer.

2. Using the formula ,
   We write:
   $\hat{a}$ = $\frac{2i+2j}{8 I.e |a|}$

My questions:
Q1: Is the answer and theory I guessed correct in 1) & 1.5) ?
Q2: How can simplify the 2nd answer I.e $\hat{a}$ = $\frac{2i+2j}{8 I.e |a|}$ to get I+j.

Comment: is $i+j$ unit..?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos I know - I , j are units. Considering that |i+j| =2 , I will say no. But we can say i/sqt2 j/sqrt 2 is a unit vector. What do u think about that ?

Comment: @S.M.T No . $|\hat{i}+\hat{j}|=\sqrt{2}$ . A unit vector has norm $1$. So it is not a unit vector. $|\frac{i}{2}+\frac{j}{2}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$

Comment: @S.M.T Yes $\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a unit vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Whenever you are given a vector $\vec{a}$ ,  THE unit vector in it's direction is given by $\displaystyle\frac{\vec{a}}{||\vec{a}||}$ .

Intuitively you are rescaling the vector given by the green line so that it terminates on the unit circle.

$||2\hat{i}+2\hat{j}||=\sqrt{2^{2}+2^{2}}=\sqrt{8}$

So the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\bigg(2\hat{i}+2\hat{j}\bigg)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{i}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{j}$.

Note:- The modulus(norm or more accurately the Euclidean Norm) of a vector $\vec{a}=a_{1}\hat{i}+a_{2}\hat{j}$ is given by $\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}}$.

So by this sense the norm of $\hat{i}+\hat{j}$ is $\sqrt{2}$ and not $1$. Hence it is not a unit vector.

Comment: Sir , How can u simplify your answer more in a way that if I am asked to plot 2i+2j/sqrt8 on a graph , I can do it or also out of curiosity of vectors , can we simplify it more ?

Comment: What do you mean simplify ? . Just plot it in a graph . The $x$ coordinate is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and the $y$ coordinate is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Ohk , U mean 2i/sqrt 8 = 1/sqrt2. Thanks a lot,

Comment: Yeah . $c\cdot \vec{a}=ca_{1}\hat{i}+ca_{2}\hat{j}$

Comment: Is ur name from lord of the rings ?

Comment: Yes it is from Lord of the Rings. I would request you to not extend this discussion in the comment . If you want you can contact me through email . I'll be glad to help you out with any confusion you have regarding linear algebra.

Comment: May i pls know ur email id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136363/discussion-between-mr-gandalf-sauron-and-s-m-t).

Comment: Hii sir , I have a physics question. I will add u in group and send

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/136764/gandalf-and-srijan

Comment: Group details to join

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to find the vector along the direction your vector is. One way of finding such a vector would be to consider the position vectors $\underline{OA} = \hat\imath + \hat\jmath$ and $\underline{OB} = 2\hat \imath + 2\hat\jmath$. Then the vector $\underline{AB} = \underline{OB} - \underline{OA} = \hat\imath + \hat\jmath$.

The unit vector $\underline{\hat u} = \frac{u}{||u||}$. In this case the norm of $\underline{AB}$ is 1, so this is the unit vector along the direction AB.

Comment: 1) Norm of AB is 2 here. 2) Ur approach would not give right answer. What if it is 3i-2j ?